# Aligning tags at the end of the line

Tags: math-mode, tags

Is there any special reason why using the `$$` won't produce the tags, like it does using `\[ \]` ?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\lim_{\begin{smallmatrix} \,x\to 0& \\ \,x>0 \end{smallmatrix}} f(x) \tag{1}\]
$$\lim_{\begin{smallmatrix} \,x\to 0& \\ \,x>0 \end{smallmatrix}} f(x) \tag{1}$$
\end{document}
```

I am used to write equations using the dolar signs. Is there an alternative way to produce those tags at the end of the line using the dolars sign?

Comment: You should not use `$$ ... $$`, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/121799

Comment: Yes Math Stack Exchange (=MSE ?) uses MathJax, and not LaTeX. Even though they share some elements, MathJaX \ne LaTeX. It is OK to use `$$` on MSE, but not in LaTeX documents.

Comment: Reading your question I am wondering: you do know that if you just use `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` you will get a referencable equation number and you do not have to use `\tag`, do you? So the standard application will be, say, `\begin{equation} E=mc^2\label{eq:Einstein}\end{equation} In \eqref{eq:Einstein} the relativistic \dots`.

Comment: Glad to hear. ;-) `\tag{...}` really is the exception, you work with `equation`, `align` and so on environments and get the equation numbers for free. If you load `hyperref` (as the last package usually) you will get hyperlinks in your pdf.

Comment: Depends on what kind of blank space. Does putting `\noindent` before the stuff cure the problem?

Comment: This is a setting of that document class. Could you please ask a separate question for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have put any examples with the use of the `\tag`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
     \lim_{\begin{smallmatrix} \,x\to 0& \\ \,x>0 \end{smallmatrix}} f(x) \tag{abc}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
     \lim_{\begin{smallmatrix} \,x\to 0& \\ \,x>0 \end{smallmatrix}} f(x) \tag{1}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
     \lim_{\begin{smallmatrix} \,x\to 0& \\ \,x>0 \end{smallmatrix}} f(x) \tag{bhj}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Zacky Double dollars is depreciated: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to